# use variable to call array element

Tags: javascript

i'm writing an app that retrieve data from a json array. This array have results in different languages and i need to set a variable to select which language to show.

now i have:

```
const descArt = document.getElementById('descArtist').innerText = data.artists[0].strBiographyEN
```

that retrieve the description in EN (english)

so i've created a variable:

```
const arrayElem = 'strBiography' + languageCode;
```

but i do not know how can i set this variable inside my item call.

Comment: hello, you could try this : data.artists[0]['strBiography' + languageCode]

Comment: Do you mean something like `data.artists[0][arrayElem]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Elemnt is a JSON-Object:

```
const arrayElem = 'strBiography' + languageCode;
const descArt = document.getElementById('descArtist').innerText = data.artists[0][arrayElem];
```

Comment: thanks, this works fine! i will accept the answer in 7 minutes